# .$save() not working for ng-repeat items in angularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have items being listed like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(name, item) in items | orderBy:'priority'" itemid="{{item.$id}}">
 <td><input type="text" class="quantityText" ng-change="item.$save()" ng-model="item.quantity"></td>
</tr>
```

The item.$save() isn't working in an ng-repeat type situation.

Comment: `solo item page` means?

Comment: A page with an item on it's own (editing an item rather than an ng-repeat)

Comment: I'm assuming you got items via a resource?, ng-repeats just iterates on the collection returned, individual items in the collections can't use the resource methods such as $save/$delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Call `$save()` on the `$firebaseArray`, not on the record.** Make sure to pass in the record to save.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(name, item) in items | orderBy:'priority'" itemid="{{item.$id}}">
 <td><input type="text" class="quantityText" ng-change="items.$save(item)" ng-model="item.quantity"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: interesting does firebase api know how to deal with an individual entry?

Comment: @Cptmaxon this is AngularFire which is synchronized collections and authentication. The Firebase SDK is much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks! This saves so much time!